# Using Chai expect dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to generate mocha tests dynamically, however I'm running into issues:

```
expect([1, 2, 3])['to']['deep']['equal']([1, 2, 3]);
```

works fine, however

```
var e = expect([1, 2, 3]);
e = e['to'];
e = e['deep'];
e = e['equal'];
e([1, 2, 3]);`
```

produces

`Uncaught TypeError: this.assert is not a function
    at assertEqual (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:487:12)
    at ctx.(anonymous function) (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:41:25)`

on `e([1, 2, 3]);`. Any idea what is going wrong here or how I would go about fixing this?

Comment: There is a big difference between `foo.bar()` and `var bar = foo.bar; bar()`. The value of `this` inside a function depends on how the function is called. You are calling it in such a way that `this` doesn't have the value the function expects.

Comment: I tried experimenting with that before, but couldn't get it to work. What I'm doing now is replacing the last two lines with e['equal']([1, 2, 3]); That seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript methods are not bound by default.

```
var a = {whoAmI: 'a', method: function() {console.log(this);}}
var b = {whoAmI: 'b'};

console.log(a.method()); // will print a

var method = a.method;
method(); // will print the global object (Window)

b.method = method;
b.method(); // will print b
```

If you need binding you can use closures:

```
// simple case
var method = function() {return a.method();}
// slightly more complex case, supporting arguments
var method = function() {return a.method.apply(a, arguments);}

method(); // will print a
b.method = method;
b.method(); // will still print a
```

Or you can use the built-in `.bind()` method.

```
var method = a.method.bind(a);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Still not sure how I would best fix my example from above.

Comment: `var e = expect([1, 2, 3]).to.deep.equal.bind(expect([1, 2, 3]).to.deep.equal)`. Or you can write something like this `function bindByName(obj, name) { return obj[name].bind(obj); }` and then you could do `var e = bindByName(expect([1, 2, 3]).to.deep, 'equal')`. Until the [ES Next bind operator](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind) gains traction that's your best bet.

Comment: Would love to accept, but I can't get it to work like this. `expect([1, 2, 3]).to.deep.equal` doesn't seem to have a bind method. The only working solution I found is my comment to the question.

Comment: Every function in JavaScript has a `bind` method, it's built-in. There was a typo in the first example. It would be `var e = expect([1, 2, 3]).to.deep.equal.bind(expect([1, 2, 3]).to.deep)`. Using `bindByName()` is easier though, and is less vulnerable to property magic side effects.